# Given g1(x), g2(x) minimize over p(x) Hamming weight of [p(x)g1; p(x)g2(x) ] ? (Or how to find minimal distance of convolutional code?)

Tags: it.information-theory, coding-theory, polynomials, finite-fields

Fix polynoms g1(x), g2(x) over F_2[x].

**Question:** How to find minimum over polynoms p(x) of the:

*HammingWeight(p(x) g1(x) ) +  HammingWeight(p(x) g2(x) )* ?

By HammingWeight of polynom I mean number of non-zero monoms, let me denote by || *||

Trivial estimate: minimum <= || g1(x)|| +  || g2(x)||. Proof just put p(x) =1.

Numerical observation: apparently there are polynoms g1,g2 where this estimate is exact.
Can this be true ?

---

**Modified question 1** If I put restriction deg(p(x)) < N with N>> deg(gi) will it change minimum ? if yes what can be said about it ?

**Modified question 2** If I put restriction deg(p(x)) < N and moreover
will consider multiplication in the factor F_2[x]/ (x^N-1) will it change minimum ? if yes what can be said about it ?

---

**Error-correcting codes formulation** 
The question is how to calculate minimal distance of [non-recursive convolutional code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolutional_code#Recursive_and_non-recursive_codes)  ?

If I put restriction deg(p) < N this corresponds to various truncations of them.
In particular working with F_2[x]/ (x^N-1) corresponds to "tail-biting".

---

PS

This is completely rewritten version of the previous question.

Comment: Forgot to write p(x) is NON zero. Otherwise we get zero Hamming weight immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you forgot to add the condition $\gcd(g_1(x),g_2(x))=1$ for otherwise you would allow catastrophic encoders (a finite number of channel errors may cause an infinite number of
errorneously interpreted input bits).

The minimum distance of a convolutional code can be calculated by a slightly modified Viterbi algorithm. Calculate the least possible Hamming distance to the all-zero path. All you need to is to snip the first edge going from the zero state to the zero state to force the first input to be non-zero. Then keep running Viterbi until the minimum penalty surviving path is at the zero state. The penalty of that survivor is the minimum distance.

Letting $N$ grow without bound will obviously not change this after you have reached that point.

I don't know what happens with the tailbiting version. Some modifications to the above algorithm probably exist, but pseudocodewords will disturb it.

Comment: Can the answer be expressed in
terms of polynoms? 

Comment: about gcd =1, thanks that it is interesting remark, but it seems to me I am allowed to ask this question for any polynoms - question is well defined as well as trivial estimate works.

Comment: Thanks very much for Viterbi, it seems I understand what you mean if have time will try to check. But still, I am puzzled can the answer be expressed in terms of polynoms - the question seems quite belong to the realm of algebra, while Viterbi is something outside. Or may be Viterbi have some interpretation in terms of algebra ? 

Comment: @Alexander: I don't think that this question has a very simple answer in terms of the polynomials $g_1(x), g_2(x)$. Hamming weight is a relatively non-algebraic quantity. The reason, why I had to exclude the case $\gcd(g_1(x),g_2(x))\neq1$ is seen in the following example. Let $g_1$ be irreducible, and $g_2(x)=g_1(x)(1+x)$. Now, if your input sequence is the (truncated) Taylor series of $1/g_1(x)$, then the output will look more and more like the vector $(1,1+x)$ of Hamming weight 3, but the algorithm I proposed never terminates. 

Comment: (cont') Many authors (at least McEliece, my favorite) define a $(n,k)$ convolutional code as rank $k$ free submodule $C$ of a free module $R^n$, where $R=F_2[[D]]$ is the ring of formal power series, such that the module $C$ has a basis with all components in $F_2(D)$, or rational functions. In other words the inputs might (in theory) continue indefinitely into the future, but must begin at some point in the past. The rationality of the components of generators guarantees that some set of inputs will terminate the code.

Comment: Thanks very much ! I do not mean "simple" answer - I mean some answer in terms of algebra (may be complicated - Galois orbitrs whatever), not Viterbi which at first look is not algebra. For example if we consider just 1 polynom i.e. coderate =1, at least algebra can give answer that for big length the distance will be equal to 2 - since we can find x^n-1 divisible by any g. Can we see it from Viterbi ? 


Comment: Do you mean F_2[[D]] i.e. D^k k>=0 or F_2((D)) - Laurent power series with D^k k>-Inf ?

Comment: Either just the power series, or (going to the field of fractions) allow polynomials of $D^{-1}$ also. So only a pole of finite order is ever allowed. The practical convolutional encoders must have generators in $F_2[[D]]\cap F_2(D)$, i.e. rational functions that have **causal** power series representations, for if the denominator is divisible by $D$, then the encoder will need to know input bits from the future, breaking causality :-). Multiplying everything by a power of $D$ amounts to just translating the origin of the time axis, so does not really change anything.

Comment: You write: "Then keep running Viterbi until the minimum penalty surviving path is at the zero state. " Can algebra help us to estimate the time of running ?  

Comment: I would prefer to speak F_2((D)) otherwise you indeed should say "multiply by D^k". Am I right - that no problem to substitute by F_2((D)) yours F_2[[D]] ?  Some analogy comes in my mind - in my "previous life" I studied algebraic curves and the following construction was important: take curve "C", point z, local coordinate "D" around this point.  Consider subspace "L" in F_2((D)) which is generated by rational functions on the curve "C" which may have pole only at "x". I wonder will this generate somewhat like a code ? May be it is something like Goppa code ?

Comment: Probably something can be said, but as the trellis may contain several edges labelled with the all-zero vector, it is not straightforward to tell how much. I don't have enough experience with this to tell. I just checked the lecture notes of a course on convolutional codes that I wrote 14 years ago. In all the examples/exercises that I had, testing a candidate pair $(g_1(D),g_2(D))$ against at most quadratic inputs (i.e. $\deg p(x)\le 2$) was enough. The reason is that one can use known bounds on the minimum Hamming distance of binary linear codes to rule out many possibilities.

Comment: (cont.) The Griesmer bound in particular turned out to be very useful in such exercises. If you are interested, I can e-mail you those lecture notes.

the previous comment (and this one up to this point) were thought out before I saw the question about Goppa codes. 

Yes $F_2((D))$ is the proper algebraic playground. I don't think there are any good families of convolutional codes other than the Wyner-Ash codes. I have asked this from a few researchers in the area, and they say that non are known. Joachim Rosenthal has some, but the alphabet was larger.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen Thank you very much ! My e-mail is al.mylastname at gmail . com please e-mail me yours lecture notes 