# Multiplication by polynomials x^2+1 ; x^2+x+1. Does minimal Hamming norm of image equal to 5 ? 

Tags: polynomials, it.information-theory, coding-theory

Everything over F_2. Let us  define Hamming norm of polynom |p(x)| = number of non-zero monoms.

Respectivly for a pair of polynoms |[p ; g]| = |p| +|g|.

Consider linear map $F_2[x] \to F_2[x] \oplus F_2[x] $ given by
$p(x) \mapsto [ p(x)(x^2+1) ; p(x) (x^2+x+1)] $.

**Question**
Is it true that minimal Hamming norm  in the image  of the map above equal to 5 ?
Of course, delete [0; 0] from the image.

It is clearly not more than 5, since take p(x)=1,
then $1 \mapsto [ x^2+1; x^2+x+1] $. and $|x^2+1| =2$  $x^2+x+1 = 3$ , So 2+3 =5.

By brute force search for p(x): deg p <16 the answer is 5.

On the other hand it is clearly more than 4. Since when multiply any two non-monoms
we will get non-monom and hence norm of each product is not less than 2.

---

However if I take x+1, x^2+x+1 the corresponding answer will be 4, because
take p(x)= x+1, we will get:

[(x+1)(x+1); (x+1) (x^2+x+1)] = [x^2 + 1; x^3+1] - only 4 monoms so norm is 4.

---

This is toy model for convolutional error correcting codes.

See the question [Given g1(x), g2(x) minimize over p(x) Hamming weight of [p(x)g1; p(x)g2(x) ] ? (Or how to find minimal distance of convolutional code?)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/102434/given-g1x-g2x-minimize-over-px-hamming-weight-of-pxg1-pxg2x-o)

---

PS

The answer can be obtained by Viterbi algorithm as Jyrki Lahtonen suggests.
However the question is so much down-to earth that probably some simple reason may exist

PSPS

Here is distribution of Hamming weights of image for p(x) deg p(x)<17

0, 0, 0, 0, 17, 31, 56, 100, 176, 409, 850, 1627, 2888, 4713, 7202, 10109, 13080, 15442, 16232, 15514, 13673, 10729, 7664, 5230, 2992, 1309, 630, 315, 70, 7, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,

It is like Gaussian.

Comment: You can get the weight distribution of such words that enter the zero state of the trellis only at the beginning and at the end from a suitable generating function.

Comment: Related question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/177465/voyager-mission-polynomials-prove-that-for-any-px-px1xx3x4x6

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.  Without loss of generality, we can assume $p(x)$ is not divisible by $x$.  Then $p(x)(x^2+1)$ and $p(x)(x^2+x+1)$ both have constant term $1$, so the combined Hamming weight is at least $4$ from the constant and leading terms.  The only way it could be $4$ is if they were $x^n+1$ and $x^m+1$ for some $n$ and $m$.  However, $p(x)(x^2+1)$ and $p(x)(x^2+x+1)$ have the same degree and are not equal to each other, so this cannot be the case.

Comment: Ah... Thank you very much ! I should think more before asking... Well, any way the bigger question behind is the following : can we generate some other examples of g1(x) g2(x), such that we can guarantee that norm of image is |g1|+|g2| ? How to describe all such g ? 

Comment: Maybe you should post that as a new question. 

Comment: Asked http://mathoverflow.net/questions/103196/find-polynoms-f-g-such-that-for-any-polynom-px-fpgp-fg-where  

Comment: Related question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/177465/voyager-mission-polynomials-prove-that-for-any-px-px1xx3x4x6